# Verify if a user is deleted or not using SAML token

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an application that I integrated SSO using Azure AD identify provider. There is an option in Azure AD to delete user. So, the requirement is to sign out from my website when user is deleted in Azure AD. We store SAML token when user is successfully authenticated. Is there any way to check if user is exists or not using SAML token?.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible by using SAML Token as of now.

Microsoft recently introduced Continuous Access Evaluation (CAE) for this purpose but the initial implementation of it focuses on Exchange, Teams, and SharePoint Online.

[Continuous access evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/concept-continuous-access-evaluation#enable-or-disable-cae-preview) enable services to subscribe to critical events in Azure AD so that those events can be evaluated and enforced near real time. Some examples of these events are:

- User Account is deleted or disabled
- Password for a user is changed or reset
- Multi-factor authentication is enabled for the user
- Administrator explicitly revokes all refresh tokens for a user
- High user risk detected by Azure AD Identity Protection